# Write to a file on the same line in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to add "123" and "12345" to the end of a word in a text file with the following five lines of code, but I have some issues.

I made some research and did some progress by using `file.write(str(x+y))`, but the other questions on this site often involved `\n`, which I do not use.

How can I fix it?

#### Code

```
file = open("test.txt", "r+")
add = ['123', '12345']
for x in file:
  for y in add:
    file.write(str(x+y))
```

#### Output

```
test (ORIGINAL WORD THAT ALREADY EXISTED IN THE TEXT FILE)
test
123test
12345
```

#### Desired output

```
test (ORIGINAL WORD THAT ALREADY EXISTED IN THE TEXT FILE)
test123
test12345
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand to which lines you want to add what... so your file just contains one line "text" and you want to add a line containing the content of the first + some content from a list?

Comment: Do you just want to append to a file?  Open it in `'a'` mode and write only the new content.

Comment: The file test.txt contains the text "test" and I want to add the words from my list "add" which contains 123 and 12345. So the desired output in the test.txt should be test123 and test12345.

Comment: There was a TAB character in the original version. Are you sure this wasn't the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may arise from using the "r+" parameter for writing. A safer way is to split the read and write operations into two separate calls.

```
with open("test.txt", "r+") as file:
    t = file.read()
with open("test.txt", "a+") as file:
    for y in add:
        file.write("\r\n" + t + y)
```

Comment: Thanks, MrFuppes solution worked perfectly. This works but does print everything on a new line "test", "123 etc.

Comment: could work if you change `file.write("\r\n" + t + y)` to `file.write(t.strip() + y + "\n")`. no need for "r+" or "a+" btw, "r" and "w" (or "a" if you want to keep the first line) do fine. and please use correct python indentation ;-)

Comment: Interesting, but what if the test.txt has more than 1 word?